# Split records from the response.getReturnValue() to different objects like Account, Contact, Opporunities in the helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-experience, javascript-controller

From the controller i am returning list response, which it is having Account, Contacts, Opportunities. Attaching the response image. 
I need to split different objects data and assign it to different objects attributes. I am unable to do that split from **response.getReturnValue()**.

Component Code.

```
 <aura:attribute name="ContactList" type="Contact[]" />
<aura:attribute name="AccList" type="Account[]" />
<aura:attribute name="OppList" type="Opportunity[]" />
```

Helper Code.

```
var ConList = component.get("c.getSelectedContacts1");
    ConList.setParams
     ({
         accId: AccRecId
     });
    ConList.setCallback(this, function(response) {

         var state = response.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS"){
            var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log("allValues--->>> " + JSON.stringify(allValues));
            component.set('v.AccList', allValues);

        }
        else if(state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if(errors){
                if(errors[0] && errors[0].message){
                    console.log("Error Message: " + errors[0].message);
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log("Unknown Error");
            }
        }
    });
```

And Apex Controller method:

```
 @AuraEnabled  
public static list<Account> getSelectedContacts1(string accId) {
    return [SELECT id, name,Customer_ID__c, (Select id, Name from Contacts where accountid != null), (Select id, Name, Closedate, stageName  from Opportunities where Accountid != null ) from Account where Customer_ID__c =:accId limit 10];
}
```

Can someone suggest me to split that data. 
With those attributes, I am finally displaying in 3 different data tables. 
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Array.prototype.map to get to an `Array<Array<Object>>` from `Array<Object<Array<Object>>>`, then Array.prototype.flat to get an `Array<Object>`. Here's what that looks like:

```
var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
var allContacts = allValues.map(acc=>acc.Contacts).flat();
var allOpps = allValues.map(acc=>acc.Opportunities).flat();
```

Comment: Awesome @sfdcfox. Working like charm..!